# Would this be sufficient validation of a product ID in php?

Tags: php, validation, integer, int

I'm working on a very small webshop with a very limited number of projects using codeigniter.

At the start of the script, the products model gets the entire list of products and stores the result as an array as a property of this model.

The product ID's are simply the auto incremented primary keys from the database. So when somebody adds a product to the cart the ID gets sent with POST. I then check three things:

- Could $id be an integer?
- Does this integer exceed the total number of products?
- Does this integer match a product ID?

Basically -although slightly simplified- I do this:

```
// Count total number of items
$total = count($this->productArray)

if (!(int)$id || $id > $total)
    return false;

foreach($this->productArray as $product) {
    if ($product['id'] == $id)
        return true;
}

return false;
```

Comment: "Does this integer exceed the total number of products?" -- this is a poor test because auto-incremented values are not guaranteed to be sequential.  For example if you have 1,2,4 then you have only 3 products but 4 is a valid id.

Comment: Whoa! Thanks mate! So silly, should have thought of it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Does this integer exceed the total number of products?
> ```

This will not always be true. As soon as they delete products this will get out of sync.

That said the better idea would be to cast the id to an integer, and the query for the product directly on the DB. Not check against a preloaded array; That makes no sense.

Comment: I'm having a hard time deciding on the best answer here since both of you are essentially saying the same. Because leftclickben's answer is split in a comment on my question and a separate answer I've decided to go for this one.

Comment: I'm not worried about which one is marked correct, but for the record, the reason I put the comment as a comment and the answer as an answer, is that the answer is responding to your actual question, the comment about the non-sequential ID values is more of a side note that doesn't actually matter once you start using SQL anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing one of the main benefits of using a database, which is that it is very good at exactly this sort of thing.

Instead of loading all the products into memory, and then performing your own search in PHP, you should search for the requested product in the database using an SQL query like `select * from products where id = :id`.